# Should I install the standalone keras or tensorflow.keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

As commented here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.4.0, the keras 2.4.0 is now focused on the `Tensorflow` implementation and distributed as `tensorflow.keras`. There is now only one Keras: `tensorflow.keras`. The Keras documentation also mention that to start using Keras simply installs TensorFlow 2. It seems there is no need to install keras as a separate package.

I note after installing tensorflow, the associated keras version (for tensorflow 2.4.1 as of now) is still 2.4.0, while the pypi.org shows the latest keras version is 2.4.3 (https://pypi.org/project/keras/). The standalone `keras` and `tensorflow.keras` are not the same version. I am a little confused which keras version to use to better take advantage of deep learning. Is it better practice to have both?

Answer (score 2):

Do not install both versions of keras. This will cause import and path problems. It is recommended that you use the keras included with tensorflow (tf.keras) because that ensures compatibility between tensorflow and keras. Otherwise some tensorflow API changes may cause errors with keras.